# InstallShield - how long license lasts

Tags: licensing, installshield

we are planning to use InstallShield for your product build. Unfortunately, I was not able to find explicitly written if you can use InstallShield and all his components after 1 year of usage.

I am aware of the fact that it works like it for most of software (you only lose right for support and updates) but I need to be sure. (I was able to find the information explicitly written for all other software we tend to use or with help of their support.)

I also tried to contact InstallShield support but it seems that without Maintenance subscription you cannot ask anything and browsing their forum only confused me more.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Fair enough, do you have a suggestion where can I ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the license you purchase. Most licenses for InstallShield are perpetual licenses: once you buy it, you are entitled to use it forever. Some licenses with explicit term lengths on them do expire. Note that the licensing implementation expects to connect to the server periodically, and if it cannot do so it will believe the license has expired.

FYI, these questions are probably easier to ask of a sales representative than of the support team.

Comment: Thank you very much, to contact the sales representative was a great idea and it deed that was the perpetual license.